# YouTube Api v3 .net library, Oauth token expiring during video upload

Tags: c#, .net, youtube-api

**The problem and what I've tried**:

Hi! I've been having trouble uploading videos that are long to YouTube using the v3 api, this is because of the Oauth token needs to be refreshed every 3600secs (1 hour). This is a problem for large files (or in the case that the token was close to expire when the upload started)

Now, the documentation says that it should refresh automatically when it's close to expire, but this is not the case, after some testing, I've been able to determine that the token is trying to refresh about 2 or 3 minutes too late, causing the upload to stop with an unauthorized error (401).

Now, I've tried using a thread that checks manually if the Token (found in the User Credential being used by the Youtube the service) is about to expire, and calls UserCredential.RefreshTokenAsync 1 minute before it expires. This works, it actually refreshes the token in time, but... by the looks of it, the Class InsertMediaUpload does not use a reference to this token, but it uses a copy, since while debugging I can see that it's using the old token, even after the thread updated it, causing again, the same error.

**My question**:

My question is basically, what can I do? is there a way for me to manually update the token that my InsertMediaUpload object is using?, or is there a way to make the token "Refreshment" happen earlier than what is doing now? Or what else can I do?

**Code for the upload in case you need it**:

```
 using (FileStream fileStream = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Open))
 {
        VideosResource.InsertMediaUpload videosInsertRequest =
            youtubeService.Videos.Insert(video, parts, fileStream, "video/*");
        videosInsertRequest.ProgressChanged += videosInsertRequest_ProgressChanged;
        videosInsertRequest.ResponseReceived += videosInsertRequest_ResponseReceived;

        await videosInsertRequest.UploadAsync();
 }
```

Thank you for the help

**PS**: I actually tried using resumable upload to continue it, but I still can't make it work, but that's something for another question I guess.